# Partial Differential Equations, how to find a change of variables

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am trying to understand how to find variable changes for partial differential equations. I know characteristics method gives you a valid variable change when you have a condition given on a hypersurface of the domain.

I have been given several direct methods, that is, given a PDE on a given form, I have to use exactly one change of variables, because my notes say so.

Aside from intuition (Trying to eliminate variables, reducing order...), Is there any method to find a change of variables for a given PDE?

This is the example I'm working on:

> $a(x,y)u_{xx}+b(x,y)u_{xy}+c(x,y)u_{yy}+d(x,y)u_{x}+e(x,y)u_{y}+f(x,y)u=0$

Comment: Is there a specific problem you are working on?

Comment: No, just basic PDEs, like $a(x,y)u_{xx}+b(x,y)u_{xy}+c(x,y)u_{yy}+d(x,y)u_{x}+e(x,y)u_{y}+f(x,y)u=0$

Comment: I am not sure. I can give plenty of examples of how these change of variables are used (including more advanced uses of the change of variables). I'll keep thinking about it.

Comment: Yes, but I want to know where they come from.

Comment: It depends very much on the type of the PDE (elliptic, parabolic, hyperbolic). The answer is perhaps a bit long for an answer here, but I made a [video](https://courses.mai.liu.se/GU/TATA27/video/13.html) about it for a PDE course during the pandemic. Check it out if you have an hour to spare; I think it may answer your question about where the changes of variable come from. (If you're still interested, 8 years later!)